# ICQ offline messages (do not show up)

Tags: instant-messaging, adium, icq

I have a weird problem with offline messages:

I use Adium on 2 Macs (home and office) and Beejive (iPhone) for connecting to ICQ and other protocols. When someone sends me an offline messages I expect them to show up the next time I login with any of my 3 devices. But that's not the case. Recently some show up at the office, some at home and some on my iPhone – couldn't figure out any logic behind it, seems rather random.

I thought for a while that it depends on the last device I have been logged in with. But that's not the case either. A friend can send me offline Messages during the weekend, i can login with my Mac at home or iPhone, yet in some cases it only shows up when logging in from office. Weird.

It really freaks me out – and no, I can't make 'em go to jabber or the like. Anyone experiencing a similar problem?

Comment: people still use ICQ?

Comment: @Keltari this question is almost 4 years old now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Adium's bug tracker: **[Messages are not received in ICQ while being offline](http://trac.adium.im/ticket/11176)**